# Are all immutable objects identical in dart if they have same values?

Tags: flutter, dart

> As int,double, string override ==operator,does that have anything to do with identity? As they always are identical if they are compared with variables having same value and data type as theres

Answer (score 1):

[Comparing number and string containing number](https://code-maven.com/slides/dart/comparing-number-and-string)

> Strings can't equal to numbers even if the look the same. We first need to convert the string to an int and only then will they be equal.

```
void main() {
  var x = 23;
  var y = "23";
  if (x == y) 
    print("string and int are not equal");

  if (x == int.parse(y)) 
    print("Converted string equals to int");

  if (x.toString() == y)
    print("Int converted to string also works");
}
```

[Immutable Data Patterns in Dart and Flutter](https://dart.academy/immutable-data-patterns-in-dart-and-flutter/) explains the Immutable data constructs in depth.

Comment: I meant to say that int, double ,string when have same values of the same type as theres and when compared yield identical as true, please consider my question once again and answer

Comment: Could you bring an example and explain based on that?